# Understanding Neil Fraser's Differential Synchronization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, synchronization

I'm trying to fully understand the [Differential Synchronization algorithm](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/) and in particular the *Guaranteed Delivery Method* (Section 4).

[image: synchronization cycle]

I do not understand why there is a need for an *edit stack* in the upper half of the synchronization cycle.

The purpose of the *edit stacks* are as follows (copied from the second paragraph in section 4):

> [...] in the case of packet loss, the edits are queued up in a stack and are retransmitted to the remote party on every sync until the remote party returns an acknowledgment of receipt.

That makes sense. But later in the sixth paragraph (the *Lost return packet* case) it says:

> This indicates that the previous response must have been lost. Therefore the **server deletes its edit stack** and copies the Backup Shadow into Shadow Text (step 4).

So, as far as I understand it:

- During normal operation: the *edit stack* (in the upper half) will contain a single entry, which is acknowledged and removed during the next synchronization cycle.
- In case of a network error: the client fail to acknowledge the *edit stack* and the server will then simply clear it.

If this is correct, then the *edit stack* in the upper half will either be empty or contain a single entry. And further more, that single entry will never be (re-)sent back to the client under any circumstance. Making it completely useless?!

The obvious question is then **why do we need an *edit stack* (in the upper half) at all?**

I'm sure that I'm missing something important. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your point is valid for the *client-server* architecture. The server's `Edits` stack is a holdover from the more generic symmetric representation where both client and server have identical function and structure (where, in particular, either party can initiate communication). While the Client's `Backup Shadow` would ideally be dropped in the client-server setup to save on space/time, the `Edits` may still use the stack data structure without any downsides and with the benefit of a consistent API. Note that the algorithm dates from circa 2009. Today (2017), you might opt to use WebSockets or WebRTC instead. The differential synchronization algorithm anticipates and accommodates such a setup where both parties are essentially *peers* and follow an identical protocol.